# how to remove child data from array javascript

Tags: javascript

How to remove selected item and nested item too from array using javascript

```
const data =  [
    {id: 1, name: 'Gill'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Gill2'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Gill3'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Gill4'},
  {id: 5, name: 'Gill5'}
]
```

if i pass strong text console.log(filterID("4", data))

then output should be

```
[
    {id: 1, name: 'Gill'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Gill2'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Gill3'}
]
```

id 4 and 5 will be removed and so on if anything came after 4

my tried code is

https://jsfiddle.net/p5fxhcbk/2/

Thanks

Comment: please add ```data``` array and what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterID(id, data) {
  return data.reduce((arr, item) => {
    if (item.id != id) {
      if (item.children) item.children = filterID(id, item.children)
      let newArr = arr.filter(filterID(id,item.children));
    }
    return newArr   
  }, [])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First we just need to find the index of an element.
Next simply get the array fragment sliced to the found index.
If the index is not found, the origin array is returned.
Check documentation for [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
const data =  [
  {id: 1, name: 'Gill'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Gill2'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Gill3'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Gill4'},
  {id: 5, name: 'Gill5'}
]

function filterOut(arr, removeFromNode) {
  const idx = arr.findIndex(item => item.id == removeFromNode)
  return idx < 0 ? arr : arr.slice(0, idx)
}

console.log(filterOut(data, "4"))
```